Is there a way to use MongoDb projections and replace optional properties of optional child objects during retrieval?
I'm using a C# MongoDb driver and am dealing with a specific collection in my database, let's call this collection Engagements. Engagement documents sometimes contain Items child object inside.  Each child contains a string Name property.
Is there a server-side projection that randomizes the Name property if it exists but leaves the rest of the data unredacted?  This has to be done during the retrieval of the document, NOT on the client side during serialization
If it helps, I'm dealing primarily with BsonDocuments and not specific C# poco objects
P.S. To elaborate on the structure:
Engagement collection has objects of base type Engagement
There are literally a hundred or so derivative objects from the base Engagement each decorated with their own primite and complex properties. Custom serialization is in place by the main platform that uses this collection, in order to properly serialize the objects based on the Engagement.EngagementType property which is an enum and helps serializer map to each specific derived Engagement object.
My job is to figure out how to retrieve all Engagement data generically BUT with certain sensitive fields never leaving the remote Mongo server and getting replaced with fake values during transfer. Fake values can be anything.
I have a list of all derived Engagement objects, their properties, their children/etc and what fields are sensitive.  Just need to figure out how to use a projection to not just /exclude/ the sensitive properties (which I can do easily), but to replace them on the server with something random or some _id field

Can you please provide a few sample documents and desired output?
